# getting mathematical operation of tow result in sql

Tags: sql, sql-scripts

I am using SQL Server
I have 2 tables :

table1 : for buying data data {item_id,price ,...}
table2 for  shopingcart data (item_id,datetime,...)

How can I find the probability of buying which is equal to = number_of_item_in table2 / number_of_item_in table 1;

which is better :

```
use :
set count1=(select count(*) from table1)
set count2=(select count(*) from table2)
and print count2/count1;

or by something like :

select c2/c1 as probability from 
(
select count(*) as c1 from Table1 , select count(*) as c2 from table2) 

)
```

please which of them is more effective .

Comment: I think they should be almost the same. Did you compare the execution plans?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the *intention* of the code, then they are essentially equivalent.  The question is whether you want to use T-SQL with variables or just put everything in one statement.  One reason to use variables is because you will re-use the values again.

Some notes on the syntax:

They will both return 0 or 1 because SQL Server does integer division.

The first is not correct syntactically.  You should use:

```
declare @count1 float = (select count(*) from table1);
declare @count2 float = (select count(*) from table2);
print count2/count1;
```

Also, the second is not correct syntactically.  Here is a correct version:

```
select c2/c1 as probability 
from (select cast(count(*) as float) as c1 from Table1) c1 cross join
     (select count(*) as c2 from table2) c2;
```

Comment: so which of them is much more effetcient